# COBOL Program to read a flat file sequentially and write it to an output file, not able to read at all loop is going infinite

Tags: cobol

I'm trying to write COBOL Program to read a flat file sequentially and write it to an output file, I'm able to read only one record at a time, not able to read next record what should I do?

Here is my code:

```
PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                           
    OPEN INPUT FILEX.                                         
    PERFORM READ-PARA THRU END-PARA UNTIL END-OF-FILE = 'Y'.  
    CLOSE FILEX.                                              
    STOP RUN.                                                 
READ-PARA.                                                    
    READ FILEX                                                
      AT END                                                  
    MOVE 'Y' TO END-OF-FILE                                   
    DISPLAY OFFCODE1                                          
    DISPLAY AGCODE1                                           
    DISPLAY POLNO1                                            
    DISPLAY EFFDATE1                                          
    DISPLAY EXPDATE                                           
    DISPLAY REPCODE                                           
    DISPLAY POLHOLDER1                                        
    DISPLAY LOCATION1                                         
    GO TO END-PARA.                                           
END-PARA.
```

i, ve tried using the scope terminator, still not able to loop 'm getting S001 ABEND here is my code :

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.             
PROGRAM-ID. SIMPLE.                  
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.                
FILE-CONTROL.                        
 SELECT FILEX ASSIGN TO SYSUT1   
 FILE STATUS IS FS.              
DATA DIVISION.                       
FILE SECTION.                        
FD  FILEX.                           
01  FILEXREC.                        
02 OFFCODE1 PIC X(3).            
02 FILLER PIC X.                 
02 AGCODE1 PIC X(3).             
02 FILLER PIC X.                 
02 POLNO1 PIC X(6).              
02 FILLER PIC X.                 
02 EFFDATE1 PIC X(8).            
02 FILLER PIC X.                                        
02 EXPDATE PIC X(8).                                    
02 FILLER PIC X.                                        
02 REPCODE PIC X(1)                                     
02 FILLER PIC X.                                        
02 POLHOLDER1 PIC X(8).                                 
02 FILLER PIC X.                                        
02 LOCATION1 PIC X(9).                                  
02 FILLER PIC X(87).                                    
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                    
77  FS PIC 9(2).                                            
01  WS-INDICATORS.                                          
 10  WS-EOF-IND                    PIC X(01) VALUE 'N'.  
     88  WS-END-OF-FILE                      VALUE 'Y'.  
PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                         
 OPEN INPUT FILEX.                                       
 PERFORM READ-PARA THRU END-PARA UNTIL WS-END-OF-FILE.   
 CLOSE FILEX. 
 STOP RUN.                         
READ-PARA.                            
 READ FILEX                        
   AT END                          
      MOVE 'Y' TO WS-EOF-IND.      
   DISPLAY OFFCODE1                
   DISPLAY AGCODE1                 
   DISPLAY POLNO1                  
   DISPLAY EFFDATE1                
   DISPLAY EXPDATE                 
   DISPLAY REPCODE                 
   DISPLAY POLHOLDER1              
   DISPLAY LOCATION1               
   IF WS-END-OF-FILE               
      GO TO END-PARA.            
  END-PARA.                             
 EXIT.
```

one more method i tried even in this works for only one record, again getting S001 ABEND while running the code. Here is the code:

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                  
   PROGRAM-ID. ASSIGNMENT.                   
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                     
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.                     
   FILE-CONTROL.                             
   SELECT FILEX ASSIGN TO SYSUT1         
   DATA DIVISION.                            
   FILE SECTION.                             
   FD  FILEX.                                
   LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD            
   RECORD CONTAINS  140  CHARACTERS      
   BLOCK CONTAINS  00  RECORDS.          
     01  FILEXREC.                             
      02 OFFCODE1 PIC 9(3).                 
      02 FILLER PIC X.                      
      02 AGCODE1 PIC X(3).                  
      02 FILLER PIC X.                      
      02 POLNO1 PIC X(6).                   
      02 FILLER PIC X.                                      
      02 EFFDATE1 PIC X(8).                                 
      02 FILLER PIC X.                                      
      02 EXPDATE1 PIC X(8).                                 
      02 FILLER PIC X.                                      
      02 REPCODE1 PIC X(1).                                 
      02 FILLER PIC X.                                      
      02 POLHOLDER1 PIC X(8).                               
      02 FILLER PIC X.                                      
      02 LOCATION1 PIC X(9).                                
      02 FILLER PIC X(26).                                  
  WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                  
   01  WS-INDICATORS.                                        
   10  WS-EOF-IND                    PIC X(01) VALUE 'N'.
    88  WS-END-OF-FILE                      VALUE 'Y'.

   01  TEMP1.                                                
    02 OFFCODE2 PIC 9(3).                                 
    02 FILLER PIC X.                                      
    02 AGCODE2 PIC X(3).                                  
    02 FILLER PIC X.                                      
    02 POLNO2 PIC X(6).                                   
    02 FILLER PIC X.                                      
    02 EFFDATE2 PIC X(8).                                 
    02 FILLER PIC X.                                      
    02 EXPDATE2 PIC X(8).                                 
    02 FILLER PIC X.                                      
    02 REPCODE2 PIC X(1).                                 
    02 FILLER PIC X.                                      
    02 POLHOLDER2 PIC X(8).                               
    02 FILLER PIC X.                                      
    02 LOCATION2 PIC X(9).                                
    02 FILLER PIC X(26).                                  
 PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                       
 OPEN INPUT FILEX.                                     
 PERFORM READ-PARA THRU END-PARA UNTIL WS-END-OF-FILE. 
CLOSE FILEX.                                          
STOP RUN.                        
READ-PARA.                           
READ FILEX                       
     INTO TEMP1                  
  AT END                         
     MOVE 'Y' TO WS-EOF-IND.     
  DISPLAY OFFCODE1               
  DISPLAY AGCODE1                
  DISPLAY POLNO1                 
  DISPLAY EFFDATE1               
  DISPLAY EXPDATE1               
  DISPLAY REPCODE1               
  DISPLAY POLHOLDER1             
  DISPLAY LOCATION1              
        IF WS-END-OF-FILE        
           GO TO END-PARA.       
  END-PARA.                      
      EXIT.
```

Answer (score 8):

You really should use your END- terminators... END-PERFORM, END-IF, END-READ, etc.

As for you problem, if I were to guess, I'd say you're not reading only the first record, you're reading all records and displaying only the last one.  Your READ statement has an AT END, where everything is done, but it doesn't have a NOT AT END to tell it what to do with records it's read successfully.  I generally code my READ statements thusly:

```
READ FILE
  AT END
    SET FILE-EOF TO TRUE
  NOT AT END
    PERFORM PROCESS-RECORD
END-READ
```

Wrap that in a perform like this and it works pretty well:

```
SET FILE-NOT-EOF TO TRUE
PERFORM UNTIL FILE-EOF
  READ FILE
    AT END
      SET FILE-EOF TO TRUE
    NOT AT END
      PERFORM PROCESS-RECORD
  END-READ
END-PERFORM
```

Good luck, hope it works out for you.  Writing solid COBOL can be very tough.

Comment: +1.. Your answer is spot on correct. All of the code from AT END through to the next sentence (ie. up to the period after GO TO END-PARA) fall within the scope of the AT END phrase. As you have shown an END-READ should always used to limit the scope of the READ statement.

Comment: +1.. I would go a step further.  If END-* are available, all periods except the required ones at the ends of labels should be totally avoided and any THRU clause of a PERFORM should also be totally avoided.  Mixing 74-style control and termination with 85-style control and termination is always a WTF?!? generator.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the reply, unfortunately it didnt work for me as they are using old version of COBOL here its COBOL-2, so still looking for how to loop

Comment: please let me know for any other options to loop, NOTE : its COBOL 2, sorry i didnt mention it before ....

Comment: @user1513777 I am absolutely dumbfounded that anybody would be running a COBOL compiler that was not yet up the COBOL-85 standard (the 85 means 1985). However, that being the case, try putting a period after `MOVE 'Y' TO END-OF-FILE` to limit the scope of the `AT END`.

Comment: If by "COBOL 2" you mean IBM's VS COBOL II, then you have the explicit scope terminators available to you.  VS COBOL II was IBM's implementation of the COBOL-85 standard.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the reply, could not include my entire code here, so i've added my entire code above in the question itself, please let me know what can be done, thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're not still waiting :-)

In one place file is 140, but definition is only 79.

You use file status, but don't check it. Your file probably does not open successfully, which you would have discovered if you checked the FS field (cunning name, but copied form IBM example maybe).

When you READ and get end-of-file, you set the flag, but still process as though you had got a record. Depending on "things" this gets you the wrong data, or gets you an abend.

There's no point in the GO TO END-PARA because END-PARA is immediately afterwards anyway.

Hopefully you went back and looked at the code NealB provided and got the thing going a few months ago...